# Unable to get value from Dynamic Drop Down List in PHP - Undefined index Error

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

I have created the following program in which a  user can update any specific records from the list. When a user clicks on Update button a form opens which has a Name field, Image field, and a drop down list to select categories. The problem is that I am getting *Notice: Undefined index: category* error message. I tried to echo it but still its giving me the same error message. I am unable to understand why its not getting category' value from the Drop-Down List. Kindly check it and guide me.

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';

    $sub_category_id= $_GET['sub_category_id'];

    $query=         "Select * from sub_categories where sub_category_id =$sub_category_id";

    $query_run=     mysql_query($query);    

    $fetch=         mysql_fetch_array($query_run);

    $name=          $fetch['sub_category_name'];


    $image_query=               "select * from sub_categories_images where sub_category_id=$sub_category_id";

    $image_query_run=           mysql_query($image_query);

    $image_query_fetch=         mysql_fetch_array($image_query_run);

    $image=                     $image_query_fetch['location'];



    echo "
            <form action='update_sub_category.php?sub_category_id=$sub_category_id' 
            method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <table border=1>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    Sub-Category Name: </td><td>    <input type='text' name='sub_category_name' value=$name ></td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    Image1:</td><td> <input type='file' name= 'file' value=$image></td></tr> 



            </form> </table>    ";




        /*--------------
        Drop Down List
        ---------------*/

            echo "<select name='category'>";


                $select_query=          'Select * from category';
                $select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);


            while   ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
            {

                    echo "<option value='".$select_query_array['category_id']."' >"
                    .htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["name"]).     
                    "</option>";                    

                }
                echo "</br>";

         $selectTag= "</br><input type='submit' value='Update Product'  /></select>";

         echo "</div></div>";

         echo $selectTag;

         echo "</form>";

        /*--------------
        Drop Down List
        ---------------*/




        $category_tag=  $_POST['category'];

        /*  
            $query_sub_category=        "update sub_categories set sub_category_name= $name, 
                                         category_id= $category where sub_category_id=$sub_category_id  ";
            */

?>
```

Comment: 1) First of all, please use the mysqli_* instead of mysql_*. 2) Use "Where" or "Order by category_id" in category query. Hope this will fix it. 3) Also, the form tag is not closed properly. It should close after the submit button.

Comment: in $selectTag , why you have closing tag for form (</form>)  ?

Comment: mysqli might be good solution but I noticed that its not working on old version of PHP

Comment: $sub_category_id= $_GET['sub_category_id'];

but I could not find any element in your form which named sub_category_id

Comment: I am getting the value of $_GET['sub_category_id'] from the other page and its taking it correctly. I have updated my code. Kindly check it. @AhmedHabib BlacSea

Comment: The code is not updated dear, where the code is updated???

Comment: See my answer for correct code, I have also explained it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are closing form before category select. So category dropdown list is not in the form and therefore not in the $_POST array

In $selectTag you are closing form, but I don't see where you started this one..

Comment: I have updated my code, but its still giving me an error message

Answer (score 0):

You ended the form and had not started it.. so thats why no value transfered.to overcome this you need to add starting of form at where I added this comment `//// XXXXXXX ////`in the code

```
 <?php
            include 'connect.php';

            $sub_category_id= $_GET['sub_category_id'];

            $query=         "Select * from sub_categories where sub_category_id =$sub_category_id";

            $query_run=     mysql_query($query);    

            $fetch=         mysql_fetch_array($query_run);

            $name=              $fetch['sub_category_name'];


            $image_query=               "select * from sub_categories_images where sub_category_id=$sub_category_id";

            $image_query_run=           mysql_query($image_query);

            $image_query_fetch=     mysql_fetch_array($image_query_run);

            $image=                 $image_query_fetch['location'];



            echo "
                    <form action='update_sub_category.php?sub_category_id=$sub_category_id' 
                    method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                        <table border=1>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            Sub-Category Name: </td><td>    <input type='text' name='sub_category_name' value=$name ></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            Image1:</td><td> <input type='file' name= 'file' value=$image></td></tr> 



                    </form> </table>    ";




                /*--------------
                Drop Down List
                ---------------*/
            //// XXXXXXX ////
                    echo "<select name='category'>";


                        $select_query=          'Select * from category';
                        $select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);


                    while   ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
                    {

                            echo "<option value='".$select_query_array['category_id']."' >"
                            .htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["name"]).     
                            "</option>";                    

                        }
                        echo "</br>";

                 $selectTag= "</br><input type='submit' value='Update Product'  /></select></form>";

                 echo "</div></div>";

                 echo $selectTag;

                /*--------------
                Drop Down List
                ---------------*/




             $category= $_POST['category'];

                /*  
                    $query_sub_category=        "update sub_categories set sub_category_name= $name, 
                                                 category_id= $category where sub_category_id=$sub_category_id  ";
                    */

        ?>
```

Comment: I myself not started the form because I don't know where you wanna submit the form.